# How to get User Data from ListEndpointsByPlatformApplication Amazon SNS C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to figure out how to send notifications to my ios application users using AWS Simple Notification Service.

When I look at the Application Endpoint in the web app I see:

[image]

For each registered device I am going to store our unique userId in the User Data section. Then I will want to send a push like so:

```
public AmazonPushProvider(AmazonProviderObject provider)
{
            _client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(provider.AWSAccessKey, provider.AWSSecretKey);
            _appARN = provider.AppARN;
}

public void SendApplePush(string apsJson, int[] userIds = null)
{
    var iOSModel = _client.ListEndpointsByPlatformApplication(new ListEndpointsByPlatformApplicationRequest { PlatformApplicationArn = _appARN });


    foreach (var endpoint in iOSModel.Endpoints)
    {
        if (endpoint.???)
    }

}
```

The problem is ListEndpointsByPlatformApplicationRequest doesn't seem to return a User Data property. How do I get the user data property from the list of endpoints by platform application?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the platform endpoint Id you can call GetEndpointAttributes()

Which returns a response with the following info:

```
Gets and sets the property Attributes.
Attributes include the following:
CustomUserData -- arbitrary user data to associate with the endpoint. Amazon SNS does not use this data. The data must be in UTF-8 format and less than 2KB.
Enabled -- flag that enables/disables delivery to the endpoint. Amazon SNS will set this to false when a notification service indicates to Amazon SNS that the endpoint is invalid. Users can set it back to true, typically after updating Token.
Token -- device token, also referred to as a registration id, for an app and mobile device. This is returned from the notification service when an app and mobile device are registered with the notification service.
```